# How to fix 'java.lang.NullPointerException' with selenium, cucmber and gradle?

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

I try to write some test but I have problems with driver.
I am sure I do it somethink wrong with driver.

**BaseTest** - for init browsers, set some options

```
  public class BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    protected Properties prop;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws IOException {
        loadSettings();
        if (prop.getProperty("browser.name").equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\SeleniumJava\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            //options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    private void loadSettings() throws IOException {
        prop = new Properties();
        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("settings.properties");
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**LoginPage** I deleted credentials.

```
    public class LoginPage{

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public final String boardGameGeekHome_URL = "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/";
    public final String loginName = "xx";
    public final String password = "xx";

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='login_username']")
    public WebElement loginUserNameInput;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='login_password']")
    public WebElement loginPasswordInput;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@type='submit']")
    public WebElement submitButton;

    public void loginUser(String loginName, String passoword)
    {
        loginUserNameInput.sendKeys(loginName);
        loginPasswordInput.sendKeys(passoword);
        submitButton.click();
    }
}
```

**Part of Test**

```
public class CompareLangDepStep extends BaseTest {

@Given("User account with a game collection")
public void UserAccountWithAGameCollection() {
    LoginPage LoginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    driver.get(LoginPage.boardGameGeekHome_URL);
    LoginPage.loginUser(LoginPage.loginName, LoginPage.password);
}
```

**Error Output**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Steps.CompareLangDepStep.UserAccountWithAGameCollection(CompareLangDepStep.java:30)
    at ✽.User account with a game collection
```

It looks very strange, but I only have this problem with cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

The driver must be initialized properly - see updated code,

```
  public class LoginPage{
        private final Webdriver driver;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver
            PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
        }


        public final String boardGameGeekHome_URL = "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/";
        public final String loginName = "xx";
        public final String password = "xx";

        @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='login_username']")
        public WebElement loginUserNameInput;

        @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='login_password']")
        public WebElement loginPasswordInput;

        @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@type='submit']")
        public WebElement submitButton;

        public void loginUser(String loginName, String passoword)
        {
            loginUserNameInput.sendKeys(loginName);
            loginPasswordInput.sendKeys(passoword);
            submitButton.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Steps.CompareLangDepStep.UserAccountWithAGameCollection(CompareLangDepStep.java:29)
 at ✽.User account with a game collection

Comment: I dont have the complete code, so do not know which line item it is failing exactly. Can you point to me where exactly the step at  - CompareLangDepStep.java:29